# jquery datepicker [object Object]

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to put the date from `datePicker` in a JavaScript variable, but the content of variable shows `[object Object]`. Could you please advice why?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 

<script type="text/javascript">  
   $(function(){  
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({             
    inline: true,              
    showOtherMonths: true,          
    altFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });  
 });  

</script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var x = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
   alert(x);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected. `alert` converts its argument to a string, and the default string representation of an object is `"[object Object]"`. Try `alert({})` and you will see the same result. Use `console.log` or `console.dir` for debugging.

Comment: Although, `.datepicker("getDate")` should return a `Date` object, which normally overwrites `toString`. Either you use a strange browser or there is indeed something wrong... but the code you posted seems to be alright, so there is not much we can help with. If you provide more information we might be able to help, assuming there is actually a problem.

Comment: No errors in console. Datepicker is working fine. if I use altField:"#input" the date is showed in input field. But I need to put the date generated by date-picker inside a variable to pass it to a php script (in the same file) without user need to press "send" button in a form. Thks

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` and check the browser's JavaScript console. (in `firebug` for example).

Comment: thanks for answer, I choose to use a php calendar instead of datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the default rendering of the date is the string "[object Object]". You need to either find a different way to view the result (such as via `console.log` or Firebug), or you need to output it in a human readable form, such as:

```
alert(x.toLocaleDateString());
```

For more information see [Date.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that worked for me... I use classes instead of id's because I work in asp.net...

```
                            var div2Date = $(".dateDiv2").datepicker('getDate');
```